# Translate placeholder text in search field

Tags: multi-language, translation, plugin-wpml

I want to translate the placeholder attribute in my search box. I am using the WPML-plugin to translate all text. How can I accomplish this?

My code:

```
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Your Search term here" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $search ); ?>" name="search">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as any regular string, you can use

```
<?php esc_attr_e( 'Your Search term here', 'your_theme_slug' ); ?>
```

So your code for the `<input>` would look like

```
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php 
    esc_attr_e( 'Your Search term here', 'your_theme_slug' ); 
    ?>" value="<?php 
    echo esc_attr( $search ); 
    ?>" name="s">
```

WPML, as well as WordPress, uses the PHP `get_text()` function. You can translate this either with the additional String Translation Plugin, or you create a mo/po file for your theme.